# gcc internal compiler error: target_expr

Tags: g++

Ok. I have a question about GCC bug reporting.

When I'm compiling Qt 4.7.4 on Ubuntu 11.04 using the following GCC with the source file QTDUR/src/gui/image/qimage.cpp as part of the build process:

> output of `g++ -v`: Using built-in specs.
>
> COLLECT_GCC=g++
>
> COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/GCC/svn-build/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.0/lto-wrapper
>
> Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu Configured with: ../svnsrc/configure
> --enable-lto --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/usr/GCC/svn-build --enable-gold=default --enable-ld=yes --enable-__cxa-atexit --enable-build-with-cxx --enable-werror --enable-threads Thread model: posix gcc version 4.7.0 20111013 (experimental) (GCC)

I get the following message:

> internal compiler error: tree code target_expr is not supported in LTO
> streams. Please submit a full bug report.

I can't submit the *.i files as requested by the bug reporting guidelines because the issue is in Qt compilation, not a self contained source file. The other option would be to create a test case, but how can I create a test case when I don't know enough about GCC internals to know what the problem is?

Thank You for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you submit the `qimage.i` file obtained after preprocessing of that `qimage.cpp` file?

Comment: Well, from what I interpreted from the guidelines, I can't if the .cpp includes any headers.

Comment: @mmoran: the .ii file is exactly what you want here -- what you've found is a sign of a serious compiler bug and definitely should be followed up on further.